# How to trigger a component transition when the components data has loaded in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a fade-in transition that is working with all my components, the problem is a few of my components that are making api calls - transition in before the data is fully loaded.

So if I have a table with each row being populated with data from the api call, the table headers will transition initially and then a few seconds later - many rows with data will suddenly appear.  What I want is for the table/data to fade-in.  How can I trigger or delay the transition until the job_execs array gets populated with data from the API call?

## views/releases.vue

```
<script>
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar.vue";
import Releases from "../components/releases/Releases.vue";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "releases",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    };
  },
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Releases,
    Footer
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div id="vue-main">
    <NavBar></NavBar>
    <h1><b>Releases</b></h1>
    <transition name="fade" appear mode="out-in">
      <Releases></Releases>
    </transition>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

## components/releases/Releases.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="releases">
    <table>
      <template>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Version</b></td>
          <td><b>Platform</b></td>
          <td><b>Status</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in orderedReleases">
          <td :style="tdStyle">{{ item.version }}</td>
          <td :style="tdStyle">{{ item.platform }}</td>
          <td :style="tdStyle">{{ item.status }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from "moment";
import sortBy from "lodash/sortBy";

export default {
  name: "Releases",
  props: ["loading"],
  data() {
    return {
      job_execs: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    orderedReleases: function() {
      let newlist = this.job_execs.sort(this.naturalCompare).reverse()
      for ( var i = 0; i < newlist.length; i++) {
        if (typeof newlist[i].version === "string") {
          if (newlist[i].version.startsWith("iPad")) {
            console.log(newlist[i].version)
            newlist.splice(i,1);
            i--;
          }
        }
      }
      return newlist;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    calculateDuration: function(time_start, time_end) {
      this.theDuration = moment.duration(time_end.diff(time_start));
      if (this.theDuration.seconds() == 0) {
        this.cleanDuration = "N/A";
      } else {
        this.cleanDuration =
          this.theDuration.hours() +
          " hrs " +
          this.theDuration.minutes() +
          " min " +
          this.theDuration.seconds() +
          " sec";
      }
      return this.cleanDuration;
    },
    naturalCompare: function(a, b) {
      var ax = [], bx = [];
      a.version.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
      b.version.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
      while(ax.length && bx.length) {
        var an = ax.shift();
        var bn = bx.shift();
        var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
        if(nn) return nn;
      }
    return ax.length - bx.length;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.jobExecEndpoint = process.env.VUE_APP_UATU_URL + "/api/v1/release/";
    fetch(this.jobExecEndpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => {
        for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
          this.cleanStartTime = moment(body[i].start_date);
          this.job_execs.push({
            version: body[i].version,
            status: body[i].status.name,
            start: this.cleanStartTime.format("LLL")
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error Fetching:", this.jobExecEndpoint, err);
        return { failure: this.jobExecEndpoint, reason: err };
      });
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a v-if inside your Releases component on the div tag like so:

```
<div class="releases" v-if="job_execs"></div>
```

and change your data object like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    job_execs: null
  };
},
```

The pattern I use:

- loading: `smth = null`
- loaded: `smth = [...]`
- empty state: `smth.length === 0`

This way you don't need a separate loading property.

Comment: when I change job_execs to null, i get an error in the created hook when I am trying to pass data into job_execs.  Cannot read property 'push' of null

Comment: In the created hook set `this.job_execs` to an empty array before pushing to it